# How to prove a MSE loss function is convex for linear regression

Tags: probability-theory, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

$$MSE(w)=1/N∥y−Xw∥^2.$$
from what I have understood, If I'm able to prove $MSE(w) +\nabla MSE(w) * (z-w) \leq MSE(z)$. I found the partial derivative of $MSE(w)$ but I'm stuck there. Can someone help me with this proof?

Comment: You can equivalently show that the Hessian of the objective function with respect to $w$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Would try this, Thank you

Comment: @GReyes gave what I think is the simplest and most clear answer, but here's an alternative that I also like: The gradient of the objective function is $(1/N)X^T(Xw-y)$. The Hessian is $(1/n) X^T X$. The Hessian is positive semidefinite, so the objective function is convex.

Comment: @littleO It's great that I was able to understand this using both Hessain and GReyes method. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: @littleO i'm being pedantic, but won't the gradient be twice that?

Comment: @HelperFunction You’re right, good catch. That’s not pedantic. I should have said the gradient is $(2/N) X^T (X w -y)$ and the Hessian is $(2/N) X^T X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence of two facts: the norm squared $x\to\|x\|^2$ is convex (this follows from the triangle inequality and the homogeneity of the norm) and your error function is a composition of the norm and an affine function. Such compositions are always convex, as you can check by definition.

1) Convexity of $x\to\|x\|^2$:

I am going to choose the Euclidean norm. In this case 
$$
\|x\|^2=\sum_{k=1}^dx_i^2
$$
and then the second partial derivatives $\partial^2 f/\partial x_i\partial x_j$ are zero if $I\neq j$ and equal $2$ if $I=j$. In other words, the Hessian is diagonal with $2$ on the diagonal, so it is positive definite.

2) If $g:D\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a convex set and $g(x)=\langle w,x\rangle +b$ is any affine function and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a convex real function, then $f\circ g$ is convex in $D$.
Proof:

Let $x_1,x_2\in D$ and $\alpha\in[0,1]$. We have
$$
f\circ g(\alpha x_1 +(1−\alpha)x_2)=f(⟨\alpha x_1 +(1−\alpha)x_2,w⟩+b)
$$
$$
= f(\alpha⟨x_1, w⟩ + (1 − \alpha)⟨x_2, w⟩ + b)
$$
$$
= f(\alpha(⟨x_1, w⟩ + b) + (1 − \alpha)(⟨x_2, w⟩ + b))
$$
$$ 
\le \alpha f(⟨x_1, w⟩ + b) + (1 − \alpha)f(⟨x_2, w⟩ + b)
$$
$$
=f\circ g(x_1)+f\circ g(x_2).
$$
by the convexity of $f$.